# Isuue with the initialization of variable sized object in c

Tags: c, initialization

What is the problem with the initialization of variable sized object like this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

    int fun(int n,int *dp)
{
    dp[1]=0;

    int i;
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        dp[i]=1+dp[i-1];
        if(i%2==0)dp[i]=min(dp[i],1+dp[i/2]);
        if(i%3==0)dp[i]=min(dp[i],1+dp[i/3]);
    }
    return dp[n];
}


    int main()
    {
        int arr[4]={2,4,1,7};
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            int memo[arr[i]+1]={-1};
            //memset(memo,-1,sizeof(memo));
            int result=fun(arr[i],memo);
            printf("%d\t",result);
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

The error is :`variable-sized object`memo' may not be initialized`

Initially I tried with this method of initialization.But later used memset().
Can someone help me out..
Thanks..

Comment: Then what happened? Errors?

Comment: what is memo? paste complete, real code please

Comment: Variable-length arrays cannot have initializers.

Comment: @lizusek What `memo` is, is already there.

Comment: @m0skit0 Wrong, check the first revision of the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22426045/1 declaration of `memo` was always there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't compile:

```
int memo[arr[i]+1]={-1};
```

You can't have initializer lists in variable-length arrays. You'll have to initialize it manually:

```
    int memo[arr[i]+1];
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i]+1; j++)
        memo[j] = -1;
    int result=fun(arr[i],memo);
    printf("%d\t",result);
```

As for the `memset` solution, it *should* work, assuming that 2 complement is used - this is because `memset` works byte by byte, so it's actually writing the byte `-1` several times into each byte of `memo[i]` (in particular, it will write `-1` into each of `sizeof(int)` bytes of `memo[i]`). But since `-1` is typically represented by a bit pattern filled with 1's, it will work nonetheless. If `-1` is represented by a different bit pattern, then you might get a surprise. Personally, I'd go with the manual initialization.

Comment: You forgot to remove the initializer in the example ;).

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard

> 3 The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of
>   unknown size or a complete object type that is not a variable length
>   array type.

Comment: Is this a compilation error?Is this because the initialization of the initial array arr[] happens at the run time rather than at the compilation?